# trigger before delete cursor error

Tags: plsql

I have the following code:

```
create or replace trigger torles
  before delete on csapat
  for each row
  declare
    cursor c1 is
        select jatekos_id
        from jatekosok  
        where csapat_id = :OLD.csapat_id;
begin
  if c1%notfound then dbms_output.put_line('');
  else
      for i in c1 loop
          delete from legjobbak where jatekos_id = i.jatekos_id;
      end loop;
  end if;
end torles;
```

And the error report when i try to delete:

```
Error starting at line 12 in command:
delete from csapat where csapat_id = 6
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "HR.TORLES", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.TORLES'
01001. 00000 -  "invalid cursor"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

The select is working. I have no idea what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check the `%notfound` attribute of a cursor that has not yet been opened.  You don't really need to anyway:

```
create or replace trigger torles
  before delete on csapat
  for each row
  declare
    cursor c1 is
        select jatekos_id
        from jatekosok  
        where csapat_id = :OLD.csapat_id;
begin
      for i in c1 loop
          delete from legjobbak where jatekos_id = i.jatekos_id;
      end loop;
end torles;
```

Or better:

```
create or replace trigger torles
  before delete on csapat
  for each row
begin
    delete from legjobbak 
    where jatekos_id in 
        (select jatekos_id
         from jatekosok  
         where csapat_id = :OLD.csapat_id);
end torles;
```